# Best Practice - Should I make one table or two for two similar sets of data?

Tags: sql, t-sql, database-design

I need a table to store types of tests. I've been provided with two excel spreadsheets, one for microbial tests, one for pathogens. Microbial has 5 columns and Pathogens has 10. The 5 columns are in both tables. So one has 5 extra columns.

Just to give you an idea, the table columns would be something like this:

```
**Microbial** 

Test        Method    IncubationStage1 



**Pathogens**

Test        Method   IncubationStage1  IncubationStage2 Enrichment
```

So Is it better to have one table for Microbial and one for Pathogens, or better to have one table for Tests and have both within it? Is it bad to have a  Microbial in a table where I know for certain only half the columns will be utilized? Or is it better to keep related items in the same table, and separate them by a column "Type"?

Obviously both will work fine but I'm wondering which is better.

Comment: What other types of tests will you get and what will they look like? You should come up with a database that 'models' your process. For example I note that you have `incubationstage2`. Will you ever have incubationstage3? stage4? Will microbial ever have incubationstage2 or enrichment? If you don't know and you don't have time or means to analyse properly, then you can always go the 'ODS' or 'Data Lake' route which means create a table for every file type with a view to modelling it properly when you know more about the source data / processes

Comment: These are currently how they do the tests and have been for a long time, but no I can't rule out more tests in the future. I'll look into ODS and Data Lake, thanks Nick.

Comment: Don't worry too much about ODS and Data Lake unless you are considering data warehousing and decision support. They are just names for types of data stores that don't bother to do any modelling, they just match the input data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to these sorts of questions is always "it depends."

For my opinion, if you think you'll ever want to aggregate the data by test or by method across pathogenic or microbial types, then certainly you should put the data in the same table with an additional column that differentiates them.

You also *could* potentially better "normalize" your tables like this:

```
Table1: ExperimentID_PK      ExperimentTypeID_FK    Test    Method
Table2: MeasurementRecordID_PK  ExperimentID_FK   Timestamp  Other metadata about the record 
Table3  MeasurementID_PK     MeasurementTypeID_FK  MeasurementValue   MeasurementRecordID_FK
Table4: MeasurmentTypeId_PK  Metadata   About   Measurement   Types
Table5: ExperimentTypeId_PK  Metadata   About   Experiment   Types
```

... where all the leaf data elements point back to their parent data elements through foreign keys, and then you'd join data together in SQL statements, with indexes applied for optimal performance based on the types of queries you wanted to make. Obviously one of your rows in the question would end up appearing as multiple rows across multiple tables in this schema, and only at query time could they conceivably be reunited into individual rows (e.g. bound by MeasurementRecordID).

But there are other patterns too, in No-SQL land normalization can be the enemy. Slicing and dicing data sets turns out to be easier in some domains if it is stored in a more bloated format to make query structures more obvious. So it kind of comes down to thinking through your use cases.

Comment: I agree, particularly with your last sentence - think through your use cases. Ask what other types of files you could expect.

Comment: Thanks for the well thought out answer vicatcu.